# Excel Formula referring to Another excel in SharePoint's Document Library

Tags: excel, sharepoint, excel-formula, sharepoint-2013, vba

We have formula in xls file as below

```
='SharePoint_FilePath/[ExcelFileName.xls]SheetName'!$B$4
```

For e.g.

```
='http://SharePointServer/Sites/SiteName/Shared Documents/[ExcelFileName.xls]SheetName'!$B$4
```

Once we download this file containing above formula, then it automatically appends local path to formula i.e. New formula will be:

```
='Download_Path\http:\SharePointServer\Sites\SiteName\Shared Documents\[ExcelFileName.xls]SheetName'!$B$4
```

I have tried to search on google, found some hints like as below:

- Use UNC path for referring to another xls, instead of web url
     path.
- Uncheck "Update links on Save" in excel options.

  But those are also not working. 
  Can anyone suggest any recommended way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my user environment, we asked them to use Map Folder to SharePoint Portal and use consistent drive letter for the mapping.

Despite this, it is not good to do referring like that. It should be all in one Excel file. Links like this is easily broken (e.g. change of file name or moving to another folder) and very hard to maintain.
Should avoid doing that.